# How to create if statements using strings in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I decided to make some silly simple code to practice on my own, and I have trouble finding what it is im doing wrong. Python displays 'syntax error' but im not sure what im doing wrong.

```
>>> x= str(input("Select a colour: Red, Blue or Green"))
Select a colour: Red, Blue or Green:
>>>if x==str(Red):
...    print("Charmander")
...elif x==str(Blue):
...    print("Squirtle")
...elif x==str(Green):
...    print("Bulbasaur")
... else:
...    exit()
```

Comment: String literals should be enclosed in quotes. For example, `"Red"` or `'Red'`

Comment: And you don't need the `str` before them.

Comment: The string problem should raise a NameError and the else should raise an IndentError but I don't see where the SyntaxError come from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple things here..

1. This isn't necessarily *wrong* (the code will still work) but there's no reason to convert `input` to a `str`, it already is a string
2. Strings need to be in quotes, not inside `str()`. Use `"Red"` instead
3. Maybe use better variable names, `x` is unclear
4. The last exit is useless

Your code fixed would look something like:

```
selected_color = input("Select a colour: Red, Blue or Green ")
if selected_color == "Red":
    print("Charmander")
elif selected_color == "Blue":
    print("Squirtle")
elif selected_color == "Green":
    print("Bulbasaur")
```

### Improvements

Since you are just converting a colour to a pokemon you could use a dict here

```
pokemonColors = {"Red" : "Charmander", "Blue" : "Squirtle", "Green" : "Bulbasaur"}
print(pokemonColors[input("Select a colour: Red, Blue or Green ")])
```

Notice that this will give a `KeyError` for a color not in the dict, you could use `.get()` with a default to fix this if you want though.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped a lot. I got the code to sort of work without using dictionaries by using the first tips you provided, since I havent covered dictionaries yet. I'm really just learning it for the first time and trying to get more familiar and comfortable with the language.

Comment: @RamisRafay Glad to help, don't worry about them if they are too confusing. I just wanted to show you that there is a better way to solve the problem, you don't have to use it until you are ready though.

Comment: @Keatinge From the way it seems to be used, I assume dictionaries map one sort of 'word' to its intended meaning?

Comment: @RamisRafay That's the way its used here, but dictionaries are much more broad than that. It looks up the value for any key in a table. It doesn't have to be strings (but it is in this case). You can learn about them at: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Comment: @Keatinge Also if its not too much trouble, how do i get the required input to appear at the end of the code rather than in the middle of it? (I hope my wording made sense here). As soon as you write: input( "Choose a colour: Red, Blue or Green"), it makes the next line the only area where one can input the answer and I would much prefer that to appear at the end.

Comment: @RamisRafay Not sure what exactly you mean, are you trying to get the input on the second line?, try replacing input with `input("Select a colour: Red, Blue or Green\n")`

Comment: @Keatinge What I mean is that I want all the conditions defined and then be able to input 'Red' or 'Blue' or 'Green' to get my expected answer. I honestly don't know if I sound stupid or not at this point lolol

Comment: @RamisRafay Did you try using the code I put in my comment, is that not what you want? It's unclear if you want to change your literal code (the python file) or the behavior when you run your code

Comment: @Keatinge i think the REPL evaluates my first line before I have a chance to define everything, any way to bypass this and have it at the end?

Comment: @RamisRafay Oh okay, well you should just make a python file `colors.py`  and put this code inside it, then run the python file. Or you could type a whole function into the repl